# Python Pandas - How to replicate pandas merge_asof on multiple columns or groupbys

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have two time series tables in pandas dataframes, table_a and table_b, that I am trying to merge into table_joined that effectively replicates an excel xlookup exact or greater than match OR a pandas merge_asof method. Example tables below:

table_a =

| lookup_id | date | a_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-03 | 50 |
| A | 2021-01-04 | 51 |
| A | 2021-01-05 | 52 |
| B | 2021-01-03 | 20 |
| B | 2021-01-04 | 21 |
| B | 2021-01-05 | 22 |

table_b =

| lookup_id | date | c_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2015-01-01 | A_1 |
| A | 2021-01-05 | A_2 |
| B | 2015-01-01 | B_1 |
| B | 2021-01-05 | B_2 |

table_joined =

| lookup_id | date | a_value | b_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-03 | 50 | A_1 |
| A | 2021-01-04 | 51 | A_1 |
| A | 2021-01-05 | 52 | A_2 |
| B | 2021-01-03 | 20 | B_1 |
| B | 2021-01-04 | 21 | B_1 |
| B | 2021-01-05 | 22 | B_2 |

From my understanding, pandas merge_asof can only be done on one column and cannot do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = table_a
df2 = table_b
df3 = pd.merge_asof(
    table_a, table_b, left_on=['date', 'lookup_id'], 
    right_on=['date', 'lookup_id'], allow_exact_matches=True,
    direction='backwards')
```

I have also tried a simple pd.merge case thinking I could fill down to the next value with ffill, but because dates in tableb can start before the first date in tablea OR could be on a date between two dates in table_a, the merge doesn't always capture the first occurrence.

Because that isn't possible, I'm having to filter to lookup_id subsets and loop through merge_asof operations and string them together which is insanely slow on the size of tables I am working with. Is there a vectorized solution to this problem? Perhaps using a groupby or apply method? Alternatively, would this be better done with a query out of psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us fix your code:

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df1.sort_values('date'), 
    df2.sort_values('date'), 
    on='date', by=['lookup_id'], direction='backward'
).sort_values(['lookup_id', 'date'])
```

Result

```
  lookup_id       date  a_value c_value
0         A 2021-01-03       50     A_1
2         A 2021-01-04       51     A_1
4         A 2021-01-05       52     A_2
1         B 2021-01-03       20     B_1
3         B 2021-01-04       21     B_1
5         B 2021-01-05       22     B_2
```

Couple of notes about `merge_asof`:

- `on` parameter is a single column label as opposed to list of columns
- Both the dataframes must be sorted by the `on` label before performing the `asof` merge
- To ensure the exact matches on `lookup_id` you can specify the `by` parameter

Comment: This is exactly what I am going for. Thank you!